# Get DataTable from DataGridView's Specific Rows with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview, datatable

I have a datagridview, and i want to make a datatable from it with some conditions. For example, when user double click one row, i want to make that row a datatable, or datagridview has a checkboxcell, i want a datatable from that grid which check column is checked. How can i do that with linq? Is there any linq way of this ?

I get a datatable with sqldataadaptor from database , and bind it to datagridview with

```
dataGridView.DataSource = myDataTable;
```

i have a working code for this, when user doubleclicks one cell in datagridview, i get that row to datatable like this

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView.Columns)
                dataTable.Columns.Add(column.Name, column.ValueType); 
            dataTable.Rows.Add();
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                dataTable.Rows[0][j] = dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[j].Value;
            }
```

I just wonder that, if there is a linq way to have this result a datatable ,like

```
dataTable =dataGridView.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(f=>f.Index==e.RowIndex) //rowindex is the double clicked rows index here
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: how are you binding and or creating the DataGridView to begin with.. ? you need to be more specific in regards to what you need if you are binding a datatable to a DataGridView and you click or double click on the GridView's Row..then why would you want to create an new datatable.. ? please do some more research / reading on your end on what the following things are `DataTable, DataSet, DataRow, DataGrid, DataGridView, ....etc`

Comment: @MethodMan i added what i wonder , i want to return a data from a dialog form, that displays user some products, i dont want to query again when user select a product, i want to send that products information back to my main form. this is what i do. I just wonder if there's a linq way of getting that row's cells. Sorry about lack of question.

Comment: you should really learn to format your code when doing foreach and nested for loops it would be more readable as well when using proper `{ }` for the outer foreach loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will get you started:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
    dt.Columns.Add(column.Name);

DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection row = this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows;

foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in row)
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```